# how to allocate space for contained char pointer embedded in parent struct with malloc. I only have access to containing struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have following struct

```
struct connection
{
    int *new_socket;
    int type;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    char *request_line; 

};
```

And I created a pointer of `connection` struct like `struct connection *con_obj=malloc(sizeof(struct connection))` now I like to allocate space for

```
 con_obj->request_line
```

Can I do this

```
*(con_obj->request_line)= malloc(sizeof(char )*val);
```

or do I need to do this

```
con_obj->request_line= malloc(sizeof(char )*val);//I don't think so
```

can anyone please tell this

Comment: @kiner_shah Many StackOverflow users disagree with "you need to cast it to appropriate type" in case of C, indeed they recommend against it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858

Comment: You need: `con_obj->request_line = malloc(sizeof(char) * val)`. Why didn't you try it? Your compiler gives you valuable information.

Comment: @kiner_shah you don't _need_ to cast, but you _can_ cast it to the appropriate type, but such a cast is useless.

Comment: @Yunnosch, you're right. I just read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: And do not forget to check `if (con_obj != NULL)` before trying to access `con_obj>request_line`.

Comment: `*(con_obj->request_line)` this accesses a single `char` and your compiler should warn about "conversion making integer from pointer with different size" or similar. `con_obj->request_line` is a pointer and assigning an address is perfectly valid. If you don't get a warning for the first version, you need to increase warning level.

Comment: Have a look at: [Member access operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is :

```
con_obj->request_line= malloc(val * sizeof(*con_obj->request_line));
```

You should test if the pointer `con_obj` is not `NULL`

Your fist version:

```
*(con_obj->request_line)= malloc(sizeof(char )*val);
```

invokes undefined befaviour as you dereference the unassigned poiter. The assignement itself is also wrong because you assign the `char` value with `void *`. You could discover it yourself if you have not ignored the compiler warnings. ***ALWAYS READ COMPILER WARNINGS. NEVER IGNORE THEM***.